# Place random positioned element into a document in vertical axes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code

```
function randomizer(start, end)
{
    return Math.floor((end - start) * Math.random()) + 1;
}

var top_pos = randomizer(1, $(document).height());

$('.element_selector').css('top', top_pos + 'px');
```

but the result is not what I realy expect from. The most of the times the element is places near to top (about 80% of the times).

Is there any better solution to place my random element in realy random position into vertical axes ?

Comment: Have you tried displaying the value of top_pos? There might be a problem with your CSS because that function should return the right values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Math.random()` will return a value like `0.318` etc.

you could do `Math.random() * 10` (or `*20`) to increase the value.